# Instagram pagination deprecation warning in response when calling tag search api

Tags: objective-c, instagram

I am getting below response when calling tag search api, My api call is 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/selfie/media/recent?access_token=Token

```
{
data =     (
);
meta =     {
    code = 200;
};
pagination =     {
    "deprecation_warning" = "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead";
};}
```

I don't know from where should i get below parameter value

COUNT
MIN_TAG_ID
MAX_TAG_ID

as i am calling first time.

Comment: are u in sandbox mode ?

Comment: Yes i am in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox mode will only return 20 pics in API call and so there will be no pagination. API response will only return media from users that are in your sandbox approved users.

The `deprecation_warning` is normal, its been in API response for a while now.

Once your app is reviewed and approved, the API response will have pagination and will return media from all users.

Here is more details about sandbox mode and its limitations:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: Hey I am not getting any images.

Comment: exactly, like i said, it will only show users that are approved in your sandbox, which is only you i guess, so post a pic with that hashtag and it will just show that only